# Express authorization middlewares; when the role is not enough

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, middleware, separation-of-concerns

I'm working with Node, and Express to handle requests. JWT-based authentication and role-based authorization.

So, every time I find an article or tutorial online about Express authorization middleware functions, the examples are too trivial in they only cover requests like:

> GET /logout   -------------- (1)
>   GET /admin-panel   -------------- (3)

Using an Authorization header bearing the JWT, each one of those URLs is easily filterable by just computing the requesting user ID to verify existence in the DB, and, if necessary, their role. All this is done in a function placed between the URL and the target resource, hence a middleware. Then:

(1) is accessible to any authenticated user.
(2) is accessible to any authenticated user who's also an admin

Now, for URLs like the following, an extra verification step could be necessary:

> PATCH /users/:id   -------------- (3)
>   GET /users/:id   -------------- (4)

since an admin can view and modify any user's profile, but a non-admin is also able to view and modify their own profile, then:

(3) and (4) are accessible either to an authenticated admin or the requesting user themselves, which can be checked by comparing the ID extracted from the token with the `:id` parameter in the request.

Example:

```
//AuthorizationMiddleware.js

const Authentication = {
  async authenticate(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const token = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1];
      if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Token was not provided" });

      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET);
      const userID = decoded.userID;

      const user = (await db.query("SELECT * FROM my_user WHERE id = $1", [userID])).rows[0];

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Token provided is invalid" });
      }

      req.user = { id: userID, role_id: user.role_id };

      next();
    } catch (error) {    
      console.error(error.toString());
      return res.status(500).send('error');
    }
  },

  async authorizeAdmin(req, res, next) {
    const role_id = req.user.role_id;
    if (role_id) {
      if (role_id !== 1) {
        return res.status(401).send('insufficient privileges');
      }

      next();
      return;
    }
  }
};

export default Authentication;
```

And usage

```
//server.js

app.post("/api/v1/login", UserHandler.login);

app.post(
  "/api/v1/users/new",
  [AuthorizationMiddleware.authenticate, AuthorizationMiddleware.authorizeAdmin],
  UserHandler.create
);
```

BUT, what happens when it's not enough just knowing the user's ID and role, what if a URL like:

PATCH /posts/:id -------------- (5)

is requested? where only the post's *owner* (a certain user) is allowed to modify it.

In this case there is no info in the parameters about the requesting user(`:id` is the post's ID), it's not enough knowing if they are in the DB, not enough knowing if they are an admin, we need to somehow be able to tell if that post's ID is *related* to the user who's making the request, in the DB.

How can this be done in the middleware's handler without it losing its purpose of only serving authentication/authorization? without accessing the post's table to check for the owning user?

I hope I explained myself.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just find that post by id and compare it's user?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, the reason I'm trying to avoid that is it'd beat the purpose of an auth middleware. I'd have to create a specific handler for posts, then another for each and every other resource that needs similar checking, and if that happens, I might as well be doing it in the resource handlers (like `UserHandler.create` in the question), and not use auth middlewares for that purpose at all